# Full Width Menu Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css

I would like to make the main menu full width in below website. It is in wordpress. I am not sure which element to edit in custom css. Thanks.

Main menu image:

[image]

Comment: Do you want background something like https://ibb.co/nuh2fd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
.top_nav .container {
    max-width: unset;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Unsetting the max-width of that container will mean that if you choose to enlarge the whole page content width, the header will always be full-width without you having to apply a new max-width to match the updated content.

Answer (score 0):

Add below css and check

```
.top_nav .container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 1230px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the css like

```
.container { margin-right: auto; 
             margin-left: auto; 
             padding-left: 0px; 
             padding-right: 0px; }

body.header_style_transparent .top_nav { 
             position: absolute; 
             left: 0; 
             bottom: 0; 
             width: 1230px; 
             background: #c42953; }
```